# @api setter invalid reassignment of public property

Tags: lightning-web-components, setter, eslint

I am using @api setter to update variable and I receive "invalid reassignment of public property". How can I fix it? I thought problem with my logic and removed everything and nothing is changed. Setter is need for manipulating with data. My code:

```
_data;


@api set data(value) { 
   this._data = value;
}

renderedCallback() {
   this.data = 'test';
}
```

Comment: An LWC should not directly update its API properties. What you can do is update the underlying value, behind the getter/setter pair, such as `this._data` here. If your setter is to update the internal value and do logic, create a local function that does this and call it from the setter and from your renderedCallback.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks. So I can't use any api method inside js file?

Comment: Not inside the same component, no. This goes against the LWC contract for `@api`.

Answer (score 2):

An LWC should not directly update its API properties as covered in the [documentation](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript):

> Using getters and setters ensures that the public API contract is easily enforced. Don’t change the value of a property that’s annotated with @api.

What you can do is update the underlying value, behind the getter/setter pair, such as `this._data` here.

If your setter is to update the internal value and do logic, create a local function that does this and call it from the setter and from wherever else you need this (here in your `renderedCallback`).